# EF4 how to wrap 2 updates in a transaction

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have two independent (no relationship between) entities. Some Properties of these get changed and then I call SaveChanges. I need to wrap both updates into one transaction, since they pose a state of my application.

two updates are executed as seen in SQL Profiler. But I cannot see any transaction.
Why does EF4 not create a transaction around the 2 updates? How can I achieve that? (I already tried transactionscope-still no Transaction seen in Profiler)

Any Ideas?

Comment: TransactionScope solves this. Check that your connection string doesn't contain something like Enlist=false.

Answer (score 2):

This should work, but you need to do things in the correct order.

Here is some sudo code:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()) 
{ 
    //Do something with context1 
    //Do something with context2 

    //Save Changes but don't discard yet 
    context1.SaveChanges(false); 

    //Save Changes but don't discard yet 
    context2.SaveChanges(false); 

    //if we get here things are looking good. 
    scope.Complete(); 

    //If we get here it is save to accept all changes. 
    context1.AcceptAllChanges(); 
    context2.AcceptAllChanges(); 

}
```

If you still have problems post your code.

Comment: What is the reasons for SaveChanges(false)?  I think it should be sufficient to just SaveChanges(true) without the subsequent AcceptAllChanges(), as any error will raise an exceptions, and scope.Complete() will not get called.

Comment: If the transaction fails, and you use save changes=true, you do not have a list of changes in memory. This way you save all data to disk before you loose the changes in memory.

Answer (score 1):

hey my records get saved even if i dont wirte accept all changes

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    Roll rsr = new Roll();
    rsr.RoleName = "krians";
    studentEntities.Rolls.AddObject(rsr);

    Roll rsssddr = new Roll();
    rsssddr.RoleName = "kriansss";
    studentEntities1.Rolls.AddObject(rsssddr);

    //Do something with context1 
    //Do something with context2 
    var sdfsf = studentEntities.ObjectStateManager;

    //Save Changes but don't discard yet 
    studentEntities.SaveChanges(false);

    var sdfssdfdsff = studentEntities.ObjectStateManager;
    var sdsdfdsffsf = studentEntities1.ObjectStateManager;

    //Save Changes but don't discard yet 
    studentEntities1.SaveChanges(false);

    var sdsdfdsffsasdfasdff = studentEntities1.ObjectStateManager;

    //if we get here things are looking good. 
    scope.Complete();

    var sdfsf3 = studentEntities.ObjectStateManager;
    var sdfsfasdfasdf3 = studentEntities1.ObjectStateManager;
    //If we get here it is save to accept all changes. 
    //studentEntities.AcceptAllChanges();
    //studentEntities1.AcceptAllChanges();
}
```